# How to convert a bitcoin address to the respective hash160 using bash?

Tags: hash, base58, bash

I want to convert a list of bitcoin addresses to their respective hash160 values as illustrated using bash :
[image: sample]

Comment: came across this repo https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/bs58  which does the job but still have no clue how todo it without such tool in bash.

Comment: Are you looking for a built-in tool package with your O.S.? Because you could use that node library in bash.

Comment: i did but its incredibly slow - if i understand the process i can rewrite it for bash which would be optimal.